# Redis Stack Cluster Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: redis, bitnami, redis-cluster, redistimeseries, redis-stack-server

I have installed several bitnami redis helm charts including redis, redis-cluster, redis-stack and redis-stack-server. The use case I have is redis-stack offers a set of modules like time series which I use in my application but the redis-stack or redis-stack-server does not allow a cluster deployment mode. I am inserting about 300,000 key/values a second during stock market hours and I need a redis-cluster in kubernetes that contains these set of modules. From reading the documentation on all the redis charts I don't see a solution to get redis-stack deployed as a cluster. My understanding might not be correct, but would it be possible to modify the redis-cluster to load the modules one each node. If Kubernetes is too hard, would it make sense to manually deploy a redis-cluster, if so how would I decide or add the modules needed. Thanks for any help, feel free to call me out if this question is not scoped correctly. I need a redi-stack cluster in Kubernetes and honestly can't find any answers across the Internet.

I did find this in the a redis confugration file where you can specify the modules to load so maybe using the redis-cluster helm chart by bitnami this could be added into the config somehow

```
loadmodule /path/to/my_module.so
loadmodule /path/to/other_module.so
loadmodule /path/to/args_module.so [arg [arg ...]]
```

Comment: I did more research and the two options seem to be using the redis-cluster helm chart and modify the deployment so that you have the compiled modules in a local folder which gets mounted to the container file system using a configMap and then in values.yaml adding lines to Redis Config to load each module specifying the filepath/modle.so - this is what I am trying